# identify which project contains a given file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution with 15+ projects in there

While jumping to a class is easy enough in VS2008/2010 with RightClick-Goto definition which jumps to the file containing the definition, but how to locate the project which contains this new class/file ??

I seem to recall it's possible using some "magic" keystrokes/menu but can's seem to locate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control+Coma allows you to search for the file by name and shows you where it finds it. If you do it with class name selected, it is not many more keystrokes.

Another option is to have Solution Explorer jump to the same file as you have open. That's under Options/Projects and Solutions and is called "Track Active Item...".

Answer (score 0):

If you install the VS2010 Productivity Power Tools, the Solution Navigator provides a capability to identify where a type (or even property) is referenced, returned by, etc.

The channel9 series "VS Toolbox" actually debuted with this feature.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/